# TypeError: object() takes no parameters - attempting to load a .txt file into a game

Tags: python

I've been trying to work through [How to Write a Text Adventure in Python](http://letstalkdata.com/2014/08/how-to-write-a-text-adventure-in-python-part-2-the-world-space/) but have run into the error `TypeError: object() takes no parameters` on the last line of this given code when I attempt run it in the command prompt. I tried to research what this error means, but can't figure out how to correct it in the context of my code. What is causing this error? I apologize if anything is unclear.

```
_world = {}
starting_position = (0, 0)
def load_tiles():
"""Parses a file that describes the world space into the _world object"""
with open('resources/map.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.readlines()
x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t'))
for y in range(len(rows)):
    cols = rows[y].split('\t')
    for x in range(x_max):
        tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '') 
        if tile_name == 'StartingRoom':
            global starting_position
            starting_position = (x, y)
        _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)
```

Comment: `with open('resources/map.txt', 'r') as f:` should be indented firstly . Moreover can u show the exact point where the error is thrown?

Comment: that it should be. line 16 ` _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)` is where the error is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Best guess

The object called `tile_name` in your `tiles` module is a class that inherits direct from `object` but has not overridden the `__init__()` method properly.

Show me the code in your tile.py module and that will probably show the reason.

### More info on probable cause

New-style classes in python2 inherit from `object` (by definition). If you call a method on your class which you haven't defined, python tries to use the super-class's method, so in this case if you haven't defined `__init__` then python tries to use `object.__init__`. But `object.__init__` takes no arguments (ever), and so that's what it's complaining about.

So for example, if you write the two files below and run `python main.py` you can recreate one way of getting this bug more simply:

main.py

```
getattr(__import__('tiles'), 'Class')(1, 2)
```

tiles.py

```
class Class(object):
    pass
```

### Alternative cause

Alternatively, you often get this bug if you call `super` with arguments without thinking about what the superclass is, so this looks similar:

main.py

```
getattr(__import__('tiles'), 'Class')(1, 2)
```

tiles.py

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Class, self).__init__(*args)
```

But you'll get a slightly different stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't get to my laptop right now but I'll post the code in my tiles.py module as soon as I can.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Yeah I got my program working! Your explanation helped

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer then if [you found it to be the most helpful to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)